# React click element on page after load with useEffect

Tags: reactjs

Forgive me that this seems like a simple question but I'm having a brain fart at the moment.

Using useEffect, how do I "click" an element on the page 2 seconds after the page loads in React?

Say I want only the second element "toggle-card-2" to be automatically "clicked" 2 seconds after the page loads...

```
<ul>
<li><label for="toggle-card-1">Card 1</label></li>
<li><label for="toggle-card-2">Card 1</label></li>
<li><label for="toggle-card-3">Card 1</label></li>
<li><label for="toggle-card-4">Card 1</label></li>
</ul>
```

...Using useEffect

Thank you

UPDATE / NOTE:

the list items are drawn via a map like so....

```
      {cards.map((card, index) =>
          <li key={index}>
            <label id={`item-${index}`} ref={labelRef} onClick={onClickLabel(index)} htmlFor={`toggle-card-${index + 1}`}>Card {index + 1}</label>
          </li>
        )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2 seconds after the page loads

Mean you want to **click** an element in mounting phase

> `componentDidMount` allows access to real DOM element from within Component

With functional component you can use `useEffect` + `useRef`

```
const lableRef = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    labelRef.current.click() // trigger click event of target element
  }, 2000)

  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
}, [])

const onClickLabel = () => {
  // do something
}


<label ref={labelRef} onClick={onClickLabel} for="toggle-card-1">Card 1</label>
```

Comment: This almost did what I was looking for. I added a bit more detail to get to the specific nuance of what I am looking for.

Comment: You might want to clarify the question more, @thefonso, I don't see how this answer fails to answer your question, even after your edit.

Comment: @Nathan the current answer only loads the last li. I need the second.

Comment: This answer can be applied to your problem. Just do `<li><label  ref={labelRef} for="toggle-card-2">Card 1</label></li>`. So only pass the ref in to your second label.

Comment: @Nathan But the <li> block is generated via a map...I've updated the post

Comment: Just conditionally set the ref in that case. Check if the index == 1 and set the ref, otherwise just set up the label normally. You can use a ternary expression for the conditional logic.